# Movie about a family thrown into a fantasy world

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie on TV once about twenty years ago and I only remember a couple scenes from the end. I have tried looking for it, and browsing over lists of fantasy movies from the 1990-2005 but I have not been able to find it.

The movie's main characters are a family. The father is a professor and he has two kids, a boy and a girl. Probably teens. The mother is dead, and the kids have a necklace that belonged to her and is plot relevant but I do not remember how.

The three are thrown into a fantasy world that is in war against orcs. I think they were called orcs, but I may be confused. The family are maybe needed to fight them, but I am not sure if I remember this or I am just assuming a common trope.

At the end, the family is back into the real world, after having a discussion about feelings, the mother and their role on the fantasy world. When they are back it is not clear if it was a dream or not, the characters do not remember it correctly. But the professor, the father, is now an expert at fencing because he took lessons in the fantasy world and he surprised some of his alumni.

The feeling of the movie was a bit like [The Monkey King (2001)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0198779/). There was a time I thought this was the movie, but I had mixed titles.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Thanks. I had read that list, but this is literally everything I remember. I can throw some guesses, but I think it will make the question more confusion. I am already not sure if I misremember something or miss some detail with other movie.

Comment: There's a lot of info still missing. You might consider it unimportant, but it builds a picture. For example, are the family all caucasian? How old is the "professor" father? How old are the 'teen' kids (young teens, older teens)? Is it a family film or something more adult? What did the necklace look like? Do you mean that the father *is* an expert in fencing because he took lessons? What was the budget (low/high)? What were the visual effects like? Were the baddies specifically 'orcs' or just generic monster creatures? What was he a professor of?

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095241/?

Comment: It is all a blur. I would like to say they were caucassian, but that is the most I can do. The kids were maybe 13, but I was younger when I saw it and ages may be distorted. I don´t remember the necklace. I will clarify a couple of points about the other questions.

Comment: Now I realise it was a typo and I changed "is not an expert" to "is not an expert". Awkward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *[Voyage of the Unicorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_of_the_Unicorn)* (2001).

Professor, dead wife, kids, monsters, fencing (kinda).

> Dr. Alan Aisling is an antiquities professor who has lost his wife and
> struggles to keep his daughters' spirits high and his loneliness at
> bay. His younger daughter Cassie daydreams about the mythical world
> her illustrator mother left behind in her drawings and annoys her
> older sister Miranda.
>
> Then something magical happens: the family find themselves fleeing a
> plague of monstrous trolls by boarding a mysterious ship called The
> Unicorn. They are given a quest to find the benevolent dragon that
> once ruled the legendary faerie isles, before the demon trolls
> arrived.
>
> They partake of the quest that shows them the wonder of the
> mythological worlds: fire-breathing dragons, the mermaids' siren songs
> and the Minotaur's labyrinth, and try to re-ignite an enthusiasm for
> life within the family.

Comment: It does check a lot of boxes. There are some things that I don´t remember, but it may be it. I will need to watch it and see if the ending rings some bells. I will come back in a few days.

Comment: @TheLibrarian - You can see the final scene where he fences (briefly) with his students.

Comment: I cannot see the video (unavailable), but if he fences with his students this is the movie for sure. I remember that it was just a quick movement, and everyone (he included) was surprised. At least at the beginning.